# Concurrency in PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency

I have the following situation :
I have a list of items viewed by several users, each item can be acquired by a single user by clicking the button "acquire" in the right of each item, I'm wondering if checking the status of the item (a boolean in items table acquired : true/false) is enough to ensure that an item can't be acquired by more than one user? or is there any practical way to do that in php/mysql ?
Cordially,
Youssef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if checking the status of the item (a boolean in items table acquired : true/false) is enough to ensure that an item can't be acquired by more than one user?

Depends on how you use it. If your code does something along the lines of this:

```
if (current status of item is "free") {
    update status of item to "taken";
}
```

then it **won't work**, because there's a gap between the "check" and "update" where another process could slip in and take the item for itself! However, if you have a column to indicate which user has claimed an item, something along the lines of this SQL query would work:

```
UPDATE items SET claimed_by = :current_user
    WHERE item_id = :id AND claimed_by IS NULL
```

This query will refuse to update an item that's already claimed, and you can check the `claimed_by` of the item to make sure you got it before proceeding.

Comment: The problem is that I will have to update and to do some insert queries, can I retrieve the update return to check if the update happened or not? and  based on this answer I decide whether I do insert queries or not. will this 100% work ? I mean waht if two users execute the Update query in the same time? (is that possible? ^^')

Comment: You can either look at the number of rows updated by the UPDATE query, or run a SELECT afterwards and examine the new value of `claimed_by`. As to concurrency: the database server will serialize the queries. No matter how many of these queries run at the same time, only one of them will update the value of `claimed_by`, and the rest will do nothing.

Answer (score 3):

In pure php no, as a php page cannot update itself on the fly.

However using AJAX is can be done. Whether it's practical is another story, as it will depend on the number of items you wish to check against. Even then there will always be a delay which will vary depending on the server speed, the users connection speed, etc.

Your best bet would be to have a message saying something like "Checking" once a user has pressed acquire, do the check using AJAX, and on a first come first serve basis whoever got there first will still get the item.

So your next step would be to look up AJAX (Javascript).

The alternative will be to do a full page reload to check if the item is still available, and display a disclaimer beforehand that this will happen. This approach will just take longer than using AJAX due to the full page reload.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't want the item to disappear from the user screen, all I want is if two users click in the same time at acquire only one will get the item.

Comment: Ajax isn't the solution for my problem, since as I have explained in the comment, my problem isn't about hiding the unavailable item, but in case two users want to acquire the same item on the same time:   both click in the same time acquire both check if item available, in this case the answer will be yes so the both will acquire it (that will cause an error, since in my database its a one-to-many relation) so what can I do to avoid the error

Comment: @EvanCarslake AJAX doesn't solve anything here. The basic concurrency issue isn't even specific to a web application.

Comment: @saywow what I would do is add a table of `AcquiredItems` it should have a userid/ IP address column and an itemID column. Then when the user clicks acquire, check if it has been acquired by anyone so far, if so, check who (if it is the current user.) If not, insert a row of data of the person who just clicked it.